# How do I Associate a HABTM relationship when not having the foreignKey?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

Given the following:
Content Model

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Tag' => array(
        'className' => 'Tag',
        'joinTable' => 'contents_tags',
        'foreignKey' => 'content_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
    )
);
```

Tag Model

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Content' => array(
        'className' => 'Content',
        'joinTable' => 'contents_tags',
        'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'content_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
    )
);
```

Book Model

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Content' => array(
        'className' => 'Content',
        'foreignKey' => 'content_id',
    ),
);
```

The Book model has a `content_id`. How can I ( if at all possible ) relate the Book Model to the Tag Model?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a HasOne or HasMany relationship from the Content to the Book Model then Tag and Book are indirectly related via Content. If you want to use a find-call on one of them and get the other as associated data then all you have to do is set the recursive variable high. Does that make sense? Also then you can do stuff like `$this->Book->Content->Tag` or `$this->Tag->Content->Book` in their respective controllers.

Comment: I am aware of this and it is what is working for me. I was just curious to know if given the structure i described, if one could associate Book to Tag directly